# Is it possible to create a model with name "focus"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Just a quick question.
As far as i know, you have to enter the model name as singular and this will create a db table with the plural form of it.

Is it possible to name a model f.e. "Focus" without generating problems in future?

Rails generated in my test a model with name Focus and a db table named focus. (So there is no real difference)

Comment: I believe it must be no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine. All that magic is handled by the [ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html). If you want to teach it about specific inflections, then you can specify them in an initializer. For example:

```
2.0.0-p353 :001 > require 'active_support/all'
 => true
2.0.0-p353 :002 > "focus".pluralize
 => "focus"
2.0.0-p353 :003 > ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) {|inflect| inflect.irregular "focus", "foci" }
2.0.0-p353 :004 > "focus".pluralize
 => "foci"
```

Doing something like this in an initializer would cause your model to be named "Focus", your controller to be named "foci_controller", your table to be named "foci", etc.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't cause a problem. You can use inlections http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-inflections or migration tags like '--force-plural' to accomplish what you need.